# Invalid Opcode when sending Eth to open zeppelin crowdsale on testrpc

Tags: truffle, testrpc, truffle-contract, truffle-migration, openzeppelin

I've been working on getting a crowdsale contract working using the Open Zeppelin library and Truffle for a couple of days now.

I can get the basic crowdsale working, but as soon as I try to implement a RefundableCrowdsale or CappedCrowdsale, the code stops working.

I can compile and migrate the code successfully using Truffle, but when I send funds to the contract account, I get the error:

> Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful
>   transactions manually. Error: VM Exception while processing
>   transaction: invalid opcode
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:37295:16)

Any ideas what could be causing this issue? Code for the crowdsale:

```
> pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
> 
> import './CBIToken.sol'; import
> 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol'; import
> 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/CappedCrowdsale.sol'; import
> 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/RefundableCrowdsale.sol';
> 
> 
> contract CBITokenCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale {
>   function CBITokenCrowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime,
> uint256 _rate, uint256 _goal, uint256 _cap, address _wallet)
>       CappedCrowdsale(_cap)       FinalizableCrowdsale()
>       RefundableCrowdsale(_goal)      Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate,
> _wallet) {            require(_goal <=_cap);      }
> 
>   //Create token  function createTokenContract() internal returns
> (MintableToken) {         return new CBIToken();  } }
```

and migrations:

```
const CBITokenCrowdsale = artifacts.require("./CBITokenCrowdsale.sol")

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const startTime = web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber).timestamp + 1 // one second in the future
  const endTime = startTime + 180//(86400 * 20) // 20 days
  const rate = new web3.BigNumber(1000)
  const goal = new web3.BigNumber(200)
  const cap = new web3.BigNumber(20000)
  const wallet = accounts[0]
  //const gas = 1000000

  deployer.deploy(CBITokenCrowdsale, startTime, endTime, rate, goal, cap, wallet)
};
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try bigger timeStart:

```
  const startTime = web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber).timestamp + 10
```

It is possible that validation in Crowdsale contract fails because of the time it takes to deploy the contract.

Also, how are you sending the funds? Maybe add some sleep time after the migration.